# "90-ые" или "90-е"?

Tags: числительные, сокращения

Как правильно пишется: "90-ые" или "90-е"?

Answer (score 3):

У Розенталя дается такое объяснение. Порядковые числительные, обозначаемые арабскими цифрами, имеют наращение, например: *2-е издание*. Наращение состоит из **одной** буквы, если **предпоследняя буква гласная** — *в 5-м разделе, в 1-й главе* и **двух**, если **предпоследняя буква согласная** — *из 2-го издания*. 
(Розенталь и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ. М.: ЧеРо, 1999. §46. Способы оформления числительных на письме)
Следовательно, правильным является второй вариант — "90-е". Хотя в обиходе и первый встречается довольно часто.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идёт о годах, то лучше всего так и писать - "девяностные".
При наращениях порядковых числительных действительно применяется правило о использовании одной или двух букв, но в отношении годов весьма сомнительно, что эту форму можно считать числительным. Подозреваю, что тут произошла своего рода субстантивация (переход в разряд существительных).

---

В остальных случаях - 90-е, как тут и рекомендует Розенталь и предыдущий ответ.
Хотя, честно говоря, не могу себе представить употребление множественного числа порядковых числительных в ином, не связанном с субстантивацией, контексте.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В практике правописания встречаются оба варианта. В правилах русской орфографии этот случай отдельно не оговаривается, но в разделе об употреблении дефиса при передачи числительных цифрами приводится пример 20-й, а также 5-го, 135-м.

Comment: Спасибо большое!